# Store in a variable all files from a folder react-native

Tags: react-native

Is there any way to store in a variable all the files from a folder ?

In my case, I want to store all the mp3 files from a folder in a variable

Something like:

```
import * as files from "./folder"
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Literally you can not just use `import * as files from "./folder"` to import mp3 file,
if you want to import an Mp3 file named sound, and its in your folder you need to use:

```
var sound = require('./folder/sound.mp3');
```

**But it doesn't mean you can store the mp3 data**

you need library such as [react native fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs)